# PHP replace multiple MYSQL table value

Tags: php, mysql

In case i need to replace table value with 500 rows contains random numbers. the problem is how to looping to get the ID 1 - 500, it is possible ?

```
<?php

$first = sprintf("%06d", mt_rand(1, 999999));
$second = sprintf("%06d", mt_rand(1, 999999));
$third = sprintf("%06d", mt_rand(1, 999999));

for($x = 1; $x <= 500; $x++) {

    $sql = "UPDATE `random_num` SET 
    
    `rand_1`   = '$first', 
    `rand_2`   = '$second', 
    `rand_3`   = '$third' 

    WHERE id  = '$x';";
}

?>
```

Comment: Do this with single query, not from Php code. What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: But i need to get random numbers with php, it version 10.4.13

Comment: *it version 10.4.13* ?? Provide complete output for `SELECT VERSION();`. *i need to get random numbers with php* And why randoms from MySQL are worse than randoms from PHP?

Comment: I don't think the version you mentioned is a MySQL version. It's more like a MariaDB version, is it? Is `random_num` the name of the table you want to update? And what kind of random numbers format you're generating? Some example please.

Comment: Right, that MariaDB version i mean..
yes random_num is the table i need to update, its only 6 digit plain random number like 085569 473930

Comment: This is example doing it in query https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=f2bd0bab44265233681aefe0821ac7ad .... and there are many other ways to do it

Answer (score 0):

whats wrong with your code?
just move the random number generation inside the `for..` loop and u are done

```
<?php
function s_random()
{
    return sprintf("%06d", mt_rand(1, 999999));
}

for($x = 1; $x <= 500; $x++) {

    $sql = "UPDATE `random_num` SET 
    
    `rand_1`   = '".s_random()."', 
    `rand_2`   = '".s_random()."', 
    `rand_3`   = '".s_random()."' 

    WHERE id  = '".$x."'";
}
```

if you do it this way, that will be 500 calls to the DB and each row will have different random number

if you want the same random number in each row, just use the `in` keyword

```
"UPDATE `random_num` SET 

`rand_1`   = '".s_random()."', 
`rand_2`   = '".s_random()."', 
`rand_3`   = '".s_random()."' 

WHERE id  IN ('".implode(',',range(1,500))."'";
```

you can also create the query in one go

```
<?php
function s_random()
{
    return sprintf("%06d", mt_rand(1, 999999));
}

$sql = "INSERT into random_num (id,rand_1,rand_2,rand_3) VALUES";
$val = [];
$i = 1; //begin ID
do{
    $val[] = "($i, ".s_random().",".s_random().",".s_random().")";
    $i++;
}while ($i < 500); //end ID

echo '<pre>';

$sql .= implode(',',$val);
$sql .= ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rand_1 = VALUES(rand_1), rand_2 = VALUES(rand_2), rand_3 = VALUES(rand_3)';
echo ($sql);
```